# testswarm cleanup action doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: javascript, testswarm

I have around 5 qunit tests which have timed out according to testswarm. I tried to reset those tests using cleanp action.
     `api.php?action=cleanup`
It didn't work. The response from the action is
`{"cleanup":{"resetTimedoutRuns":0}}`

What can be the issue here ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some possible reasons:

- The update to the database failed
- The read/write permissions failed
- The session timed out